# how to check repeated elements in as string sequence/array?

Tags: xslt

I am using xslt 1.0 stylesheet to worlk on xml file data.

I have a variable in xslt which conatins many string separated by white space or new line charater.

i.e. the variable is "ServiceList", when I print it using follwong,

```
<xsl:value-of select="$ServiceList"/>
```

It prints following out put

```
hgd.sdf.gsdf sdf.sdh.duyg dsf.sdf.suos
jhs.sdu.sdfi
hdf.sdi.seij dsf.dsf.diuh
edr.sdi.sdhg dfh.dfg.dfg.fdg.idjf kjs.dfh.dfgj djg.dfs.dgji
```

I used follwing code to get each string separately.

```
<xsl:variable name="tokenizedSample" select="str:tokenize($ServiceList,'&#xa;')"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$tokenizedSample">
      <xsl:variable name="serviceProvide" select="."/>
         <xsl:variable name="tokenized1" select="str:tokenize($serviceProvide,' ')"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="$tokenized1">
            <xsl:variable name="serviceP" select="."/>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$serviceP"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

the above code give me each string as separate one.

I have to chek is there any repeating string in above sequence/array. If it repeates it should show me the string is repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be so much easier in XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:variable name="tokenizedSample" select="tokenize($ServiceList, '&#xa;')"/>
<xsl:if test="count($tokenizedSample) != count(distinct-values($tokenizedSample))">...
```

Comment: but i m using XSLT 1.0 so can u suggest solution for this version.