# how to avoid getting repeated strings from string variable?

Tags: xslt, duplicates

I have a variable `serviceProvideList` that contains string values.

I use following code to get each string separately:

```
<xsl:variable name="tokenizedSample" select="str:tokenize($serviceProvideList,'&#xa;')"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$tokenizedSample">
  <xsl:variable name="weakProvide" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="tokenized" select="str:tokenize($weakProvide,' ')"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="$tokenized">
    <xsl:variable name="weakP" select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$weakP"/> 
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**How can I avoid repeating values in the variable `serviceProvideList`?**

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054688/how-to-check-repeated-elements-in-as-string-sequence-array. Please don't ask the same question more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude tokens, which have precedings with same value, from `for-each` loop :

```
<xsl:for-each select="$tokenizedSample[ not(preceding-sibling::* = .) ]">
```

Comment: Are you sure preceding-sibling will work, when the items in the for-each sequence are not nodes?

Comment: exslt function `str:tokenize` result is node-set. [doc](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html)

Comment: Ah... I was assuming it was the same as the XPath 2.0 `tokenize()` function.